# automatic insert of object on new page

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

How can I have an object in the same spot of every page on a word document?
Almost like a header, but instead, I'd like to insert it and have it automatically appear in the middle of the page, that way when I fill a page, and move to the next, it's already there. Is there a way to do this?

I want to insert a vertical ruler, and a heading reading "notes" on the right side of every page to be used as a notes section of my document.
If I type, I don't want the font to go beyond the vertical ruler.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're actually asking for is to use **Page Columns**. This will allow you to split the content of your page into separate columns, one for the main content and the other for notes.

1. Choose **Page Layout** from the menu
2. Select the **Columns** drop down
3. Choose **More Columns**

You will want to select options like below to get the desired layout. **Equal column width** must be unchecked in order to get columns of different sizes.

[image]

Note there are a few things you need to know to use columns correctly.

- When the content of your first column of a page is complete to move
  to the second column you need to use **Page Layout -> Insert Breaks
  -> Column**. Then you can start writing in the notes column.
- Once the notes column for the page is complete to move to the next
  page you need to insert another column break as before or a page
  break.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a watermark for every page

Comment: watermark won't work, it will be written over. But that's a good idea thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could be fiddly (depending on how often you're doing this) but, maybe having a background image, and on top of that a Text Box?